# PySpark groupBy indexerror: list out of range

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a csv file(including header) in my local system,on which im trying to perform groupBy function i.e group by purpose and sum of amount per purpose.the commands i've typed on pyspark console are as follows

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql import Row
csv_data=sc.textFile("/project/sample.csv").map(lambda p: p.split(",")) 
header = csv_data.first()
csv_data = csv_data.filter(lambda p:p != header)
df_csv  =  csv_data.map(lambda p: Row(checkin_acc  =  p[0],  duration = 
int(p[1]), credit_history = p[2], purpose = p[3], amount = int(p[4]),
svaing_acc = p[5], present_emp_since = p[6], inst_rate = int(p[7]), 
personal_status = p[8], other_debtors = p[9],residing_since = int(p[10]), 
property = p[11], age = int(p[12]), inst_plans = p[13], housing = p[14], 
num_credits = int(p[15]), job = p[16], dependents = int(p[17]), telephone = 
p[18], foreign_worker = p[19], status = p[20])).toDF()

grouped = df_csv.groupBy('purpose').sum('amount')
grouped.show()
```

```
[Stage 9:>                                                          (0 + 2) / 2]18/03/22 10:34:52 ERROR executor.Executor: Exception in task 1.0 in stage 9.0 (TID 10)
org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 177, in main
    process()
  File "/opt/spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 172, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "/opt/spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 268, in dump_stream
    vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <lambda>
IndexError: list index out of range

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:193)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.next(PythonRDD.scala:156)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.next(PythonRDD.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.next(InterruptibleIterator.scala:40)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:4
```

How do i get around this error?

Comment: try `grouped = df.groupby(['purpose','housing']).sum('amount')`

Comment: This error means there are less than 20 fields in your csv file. Also, I see that you want to filter out header row, so try this:

csv_data = spark.read.option('header','false').option('inferSchema','true').csv('/project/sample.csv')

This option is available only if you are using spark version 2+

Answer (score 0):

If you use pyspark 2+ you can use [spark.read.csv](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader.csv).

```
df = spark.read.csv ("project/sample.csv", header=True)
```

If you want to set the column names and tyoes yourself you can define a schema as well with [StructType](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.types.StructType) and pass it with the `schema` kwarg.

Answer (score 0):

> > IndexError: list index out of range

Above error simply means that **there aren't 20 fields generated when you split the lines** of text file using ,

**filter solution**

One way is *to filter out all the lines whose length is less than 20*

```
csv_data=sc.textFile("/project/sample.csv").map(lambda p: p.split(","))
header = csv_data.first()
csv_data = csv_data.filter(lambda p:p != header)\
    .filter(lambda x: len(x) == len(header))    #filter added 
df_csv  =  csv_data.map(lambda p: Row(checkin_acc=p[0],
                                      duration=int(p[1]),
                                      credit_history=p[2],
                                      purpose=p[3],
                                      amount=int(p[4]),
                                      ..... #the rest of the codes are same
```

**adding dummy data**

Another solution is *to add dummy data to the lines whose length is less than 20*

```
#function definition for adding dummy strings in case of less fields in data
def addDummy(arr, header):
    headerLength = len(header)
    arrayLength = len(arr)
    if arrayLength > headerLength:
        return arr[:headerLength-1]
    elif arrayLength < headerLength:
        return arr + ["dummy" for x in range(0, headerLength-arrayLength)]
    else:
        return arr

csv_data=sc.textFile("/project/sample.csv").map(lambda p: p.split(","))
header = csv_data.first()
csv_data = csv_data.filter(lambda p:p != header)\
    .map(lambda p: addDummy(p, header))   #map function added for checking length and adding dummy string in case of less fields
df_csv  =  csv_data.map(lambda p: Row(checkin_acc=p[0],
                                      duration=int(p[1]),
                                      credit_history=p[2],
                                      purpose=p[3],
                                      amount=int(p[4]),
                                      svaing_acc=p[5],
                                      .... #the rest of the codes are same as in the question
```